# Beginner Quaternion clarification

Tags: math, vector, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to programmatically visualise a vector point but I want to clarify my output result.

If a vector `p = i = [1,0,0]` rotate by 90 degree about the x-axis, then quaternion `q` is: `q = cos(45) + [1,0,0]*sin(45) = 0.707 + 0.707*i`.

`pn = qpq-1;`

Now calculate `pn`: `(0.707+0.707*i)(i)(0.707-0.707*i) = i`.

So, the rotated vector `pn = [1,0,0]`. Which is `p=pn`.

Is `p=pn` correct? If it is can anyone explain it? or is this a special property of quaternions?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS. Thank you for your suggestion. I am trying to visualizing the vector point programmatically mentioned in this question. so I want to clarify my output result.

Comment: If you rotate a vector along its *own* direction it will not change. This has nothing to do with quaternions. (Also, the two definitions of `i` are confusing - you are using it both as the rotation axis and as the imaginary unit.)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks, I used ' i ' in vector p as a quaternion, is 0+1*i+0*j+0*k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you provided, you basically rotate a vector around itself (i.e. the axis of rotation is equal to the rotated vector, in this case [1,0,0]). As said in the comments, rotating a vector around itself, leaves it intact, regardless of the rotation angle.

Try your example where the rotated vector is along the y-axis [0,1,0], and the rotation axis is [1,0,0]. Maybe [this](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToQuaternion/examples/index.htm) will help you visualize some basic rotations.

Also, be mindful that a rotation of vector `v` using a unit quaternion `q` is given by:

`Imaginary{q * [0, v_x, v_y, v_z] * conjugate(q)}`